# Job Alert functionality on ruby on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am making a job board and am in the process of making a subscriber list for job seeker who, if willing, can be sent a notification email that the job of their interest has been posted.  I have tried google in order to come up with how to start making such functionality but couldn't find something I could use.

I am using [sedngrid](http://sendgrid.com/) for sending emails (transactional) which is currently working fine. I wanted to ask how should i make the job alert functionality .

What comes to mind is:

- Making a subscriber model
- On every Friday night, find all applicants which has subscribed to the job alert.
- Find these applicants interests (tags)
- Check if any jobs with these tags has been posted in the week.
- Send emails to the applicants email.

Is there any gem or gems which give this functionality, or a tutorial?

Comment: Common dude, this place ain't to help you write/decide architectures. Rather, use this space to help you overcome tech-issues/bugs. Anyways, you are on the right track. Use Cron jobs. It ain't anything complex to go for Gems. Just a subscribe Model and use has_many/belongs_to relationships. 
You should be good to go!

Comment: To Satya.. Common dude looks like you have asked a similar noob question not long ago....      


Am a bit confused, If I have to signup for Worker-Dyno to get the delayed-jobs working. This article didn't specify any : http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/delayed-job#setting_up_delayed_job

Please, help me out.

Thanks

This is the question you asked

Comment: Thanks satya. I will try to do as you said and will definitely try to ask more specific question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need gems really.

The Job model will need to have:

```
belongs_to: location
belongs_to: category
belongs_to: company
belongs_to: salary_range
```

You might (for simplicity) have the above as plain-attributes instead of separate models. But, I would opt them to be separate models.

Create a model Subscribe that holds the user_id and their interests, say company_id or job_location_id. I rather say, this should be a polymorphic association like :

```
user_id (integer)
subscribe_type, subscribe_id (links to location/company/job-category)
```

1. Write a Cron Job that runs daily/weekly/periodically (use whenever gem) that finds the delta of jobs created from the last-cron-run till date.
2. Loop on the jobs and find the corresponding subscriptions for its location, job-category, company & etc.
3. Send emails to the corresponding folks.

While enhancing the app, you will face 2 issues:

1. Instead of sending one email per every job, is there a way to send one-single-email to the user about all the jobs he is interested in. This is called Email-Digest.
2. What if any job-details are changed? Should you update the user about the changed-job too?